# Could not parse the remainder error on django url parameters

Tags: python, django

I get the following error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '=' from '='
```

on the following line:

```
<a href="{%url 'secrets:like_it' id = secret.id%}">Like</a>
```

Comment: You should post your `urls = ( ... )`, the problem is most probably there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<a href="{%url 'secrets:like_it' id = secret.id%}">Like</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{% url 'secrets:like_it' id=secret.id %}">Like</a>
```

mind the spaces around the `=`

**also**
If you have any issues, post the related code. In this case it would be quite useful (if it was not related to the missing spaces) to see your `urls.py` or `secrets.urls` if you have split your urls into your apps (as you should in the most situations)